# How to zebra-stripe a GridView with jquery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, gridview

Suppose I have three gridviews on my asp.net page.

How to select one GridView from those Gridviews in that ASP.NET page and Zebra-Stripe it using JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define css classes for the even and odd rows and use jQuery to add the classes to the tr elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%= myGridView.ClientID %> tbody tr:even").addClass("even");
    $("#<%= myGridView.ClientID %> tbody tr:odd").addClass("odd");
});
```